# Place cursor at the end of UITextView under UITest

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, xcode-ui-testing

This is how I clear `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` in UITests.

```
extension XCUIElement {

   func clear() {

      tap()

      while (value as! String).characters.count > 0 {
         XCUIApplication().keys["delete"].tap()
      }
   }
}
```

**Example of use:**

```
descriptionTextView.type("Something about Room.")
descriptionTextView.clear()
```

If I run UITests, it always tap at the beginning of UITextView.

How to tap at the end?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can tap on the lower right corner to place the cursor at the end of the text view.

Additionally you can improve the speed of deletion by preparing a `deleteString` containing a number of `XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete` that wipes your entire text field at once.

```
extension XCUIElement {
   func clear() {
      guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
          XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
          return
      }

      let lowerRightCorner = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.9, 0.9))
      lowerRightCorner.tap()

      let deleteString = [String](count: stringValue.characters.count + 1, repeatedValue: XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete)
      self.typeText(deleteString.joinWithSeparator(""))
   }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem and i am checking textfield into safari browser.. but this solution doesn't work for me. Can you help me to calculate exact vector point for element ?

Answer (score 2):

This is Tomas Camin's solution adapted for Swift 5.3 (Xcode 12):

```
extension XCUIElement {
    public func clear() {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }

        let lowerRightCorner = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.9))
        lowerRightCorner.tap()

        let deleteString = String(repeating: XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue, count: stringValue.count)
        self.typeText(deleteString)
    }
}
```

Comment: First Solution Working without localisation and strange tap() behaviour. Thank you